# How to run through a function again once it reaches the end?

Tags: javascript

How to run through the loop again once it reaches the last value in the array?

I would like to run the function `init()` again once its completed because more DOM elements `myElement` get ajaxed in once they have been clicked on.

I have tried running the `init` function after the `setTimeout` but that doesnt work and tried checking for last element on the array with `btn.length -1` still doesnt work.

```
function doSetTimeout(index, btn) {

    setTimeout(function() { 
        jQuery(btn[index]).click(); 
    }, index  * 1500);

    //init();   

}

function init() {

    var btn = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.myElement'));

    var index;

    for (index = 0; index < btn.length; index++) {

        doSetTimeout(index, btn)

    }

}

init();
```

Comment: I suggest you trigger the function call from the ajax response callback (rather than a timer).

Comment: Do you really need a delay of 1.5 seconds here?

Comment: @SpiderPig The delays is there so all the elements don't removed at once rather one after the other

Comment: @BenAston I don't have access to the ajax response, I'm creating an external module that clicks on DOM elements.

Comment: @Grundizer like Selenium?

Comment: Yeah, quite similar to Selenium

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
function init() {

    var btn = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.myElement'));

    var index = 0;

    function click() {
      setTimeout(function() {
          if(index < btn.length) {
            jQuery(btn[index++]).click();
            click();
          } else {
            init();
          }
      }, 1500);
    }
    click();
}
```

Comment: This does work :) I like how you've simplified the solution.
didn't realize I could increment index without using a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a "dumb" check based on a timer then use the following idiom:

```
doWhateverYouHaveToDo();

function doWhateverYouHaveToDo() {
  // ...
  setTimeout(doWhateverYouHaveToDo, 1500);
}
```

This will run `doWhateverYouHaveToDo` approximately every 1.5 seconds, waiting for each invocation to complete before proceeding.